# Strip seconds from mySQL time and do am/pm

Tags: php, mysql, time, formatting

## EDIT: This is NOT the way to do it. See answer below.

Not sure if I am allowed to post solutions but wasted 10 mins looking for this and hacked it in the end ... in about 10 mins.

If you store 10:20 in mySQL it comes back as 10:20:00. If you want 10:20 then:

```
    $time= explode (':', $time);
    $ampm="am";
    if ($time[0]>12) {$time[0]=$time[0]-12; $ampm="pm";};
    echo "$time[0]:$time[1]  $ampm,";
```

where `$time` is the time in from mySQL.

Comment: There's a few ways around this.
substr() also works. Alternatively, my preferred solution, which whilst is more expensive, but is language agnostic, is to convert it to a DateTime Object and the use the format() available as part of the DateTime Object to get the correct format I desire. More expensive, but a much more reusable technique.

Comment: Yep many ways to skin this cat but could not see one listed when I was sleep deprived and trying to do this. Just trying to be helpful (see once again I have been minused). Will probably use the `TIME-FORMAT` function when I tidy up my experimental code. Thanks for the input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just transform it in your query using [`TIME_FORMAT()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_time-format):

```
SELECT TIME_FORMAT(time_column, "%h:%i%p") as time
...
```

Comment: Thanks for that. I may be a little dense (lack of sleep) but I could not wok out actually how to use `TIME_FORMAT` when I went to http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html. Your couple of extra words make it clear. Thanks. I may well use on the next rewrite.

Comment: Dang was going to PM you to say thanks for the edit but no PM I see. I really don't understand why I have been -1ed. I looked and found no obvious answer for queries like "Remove seconds from end of TIME mysql". Thought would leave something for others who hit the same problem. Keep trying to leave useful notes for others but rep too low. Now even lower. Frustrating. How do I improve my rep if I cannot help? Curious to know. Serious question. TIA.